# Comparing list and returning odd element in list query

Tags: python

Given two almost identical lists of worker IDs x and y where one of the lists contains an additional ID, write a function solution(x, y) that compares the lists and returns the additional ID.

For example, given the lists x = [13, 5, 6, 2, 5] and y = [5, 2, 5, 13], the function solution(x, y) would return 6 because the list x contains the integer 6 and the list y doesn't. Given the lists x = [14, 27, 1, 4, 2, 50, 3, 1] and y = [2, 4, -4, 3, 1, 1, 14, 27, 50], the function solution(x, y) would return -4 because the list y contains the integer -4 and the list x doesn't.

In each test case, the lists x and y will always contain n non-unique integers where n is at least 1 but never more than 99, and one of the lists will contain an additional unique integer which should be returned by the function. The same n non-unique integers will be present on both lists, but they might appear in a different order like in the examples above. Commander Lambda likes to keep the numbers short, so every worker ID will be between -1000 and 1000.

Here is the code I have tried to come up with - which doesnt work any help would be appreciated

```
def solution(x,y):
    non_match_a  = set(x)-set(y)
    non_match_b  = set(y)-set(x)
    non_match = list(non_match_a) + list(non_match_b)
    return non_match

input = solution([x],[y])
 
non_match = solution(y, x)
```

Comment: Your solution function looks fine, but the way you're calling it doesn't make any sense because you haven't defined `x` or `y`.  Are you trying to get input from the user and then try your solution on it?  Try `print(solution(input("First list: ").split(), input("Second list: ").split()))`.  (Note that you need to *not* assign something to `input` with a line like `input = ...`; delete that line from your code!)

Comment: An easier version of `solution` than the two subtractions would be the XOR operator `^`: you can do it in one line as `return list(set(x) ^ set(y))`

Comment: "the lists x and y will always contain n non-unique integers" I assume the issue with your code is "non-unique"

Comment: `set` is not the right answer, because it eliminates duplicates.  Just sort the two lists and scan them until you find a mismatch.

Comment: if I evaluate `solution([1,2,2], [1,2])` should the result be `[2]`?

Comment: @TimRoberts that's efficient in memory, but inefficient in computation

Comment: Ah, I missed the "non-unique" part -- in that case do the double-subtraction thing but use `collections.Counter` instead of `set`.  :)

Comment: @njzk2 -- It's `O(n)` plus the cost of the sort.  That's not inefficient, compared to constructing 4 sets and doing two intersections.

Comment: @TimRoberts so, `O(n*log(n))`, then, which is the cost of the sort. Constructing 4 sets and doing 2 intersections is `O(n)` (same for using `Counter`, too)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments, you can use `collections.Counter` to solve this.

```
def solution(x, y):
  cx, cy = Counter(x), Counter(y)
  return [k for k in cx.keys() | cy.keys() 
            if not ((a := cx.get(k)) and (b := cy.get(k))) or a != b]
```

A key from either `Counter` is the answer if it's either not in both counts, or not there in the same quantity.

Consider breaking this down for `[14, 27, 1, 4, 2, 50, 3, 1]` and `[2, 4, -4, 3, 1, 1, 14, 27, 50]`:

```
>>> a = Counter([14, 27, 1, 4, 2, 50, 3, 1])
>>> b = Counter([2, 4, -4, 3, 1, 1, 14, 27, 50])
>>> a
Counter({1: 2, 14: 1, 27: 1, 4: 1, 2: 1, 50: 1, 3: 1})
>>> b
Counter({1: 2, 2: 1, 4: 1, -4: 1, 3: 1, 14: 1, 27: 1, 50: 1})
>>> a.keys()
dict_keys([14, 27, 1, 4, 2, 50, 3])
>>> b.keys()
dict_keys([2, 4, -4, 3, 1, 14, 27, 50])
>>> a.keys() | b.keys()
{1, 2, 3, 4, 14, 50, 27, -4}
```

So there are all of the keys, and we have the counts of them in each list.

If we iterate over these keys, trying to `get` it from each `Counter` will either return the count, or `None` if it's not present. If the key isn't present in both, then clearly it's a difference. If it's present in both, but the count is different, again, it's a difference.

Comment: this looks a lot more complex than simply subtracting the 2 counters: `return list(cx - cy) + list(cy - cx)`

Comment: I suggest you add an explanation of why using a Counter is solving the issue (the comments may be removed), and what the issue actually is

Answer (score 0):

Two ways using xor:

```
def solution(x, y):
    xor = 0
    for z in x + y:
        xor ^= z
    return xor
```

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import xor

def solution(x, y):
    return reduce(xor, x + y)
```

You might not need to import `reduce`, if that's Google foobar and it still uses Python 2. And you could avoid building the extra list `x + y` to save memory, but with only up to 199 elements, that's not worth any effort.

Two ways using sums:

```
def solution(x, y):
    x, y = sorted([x, y], key=len)
    return sum(y) - sum(x)
```

```
def solution(x, y):
    return (sum(y) - sum(x)) * (-1) ** (len(x) > len(y))
```

Answer (score -1):

Sort each list then enumerate them in parallel (zip) until you find a difference. You know that the lists differ by one value. Therefore the value from the longest list is what you're looking for.

Hence:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def solution(x, y):
    for _x, _y in zip_longest(sorted(x), sorted(y)):
        if _x != _y:
            return _x if len(x) > len(y) else _y

x = [13, 5, 6, 2, 5]
y = [5, 2, 5, 13]

print(solution(y, x))
```

**Output:**

```
6
```

Comment: this doesn't explain why the OP's solution doesn't work, and has higher overall complexity.

Comment: @njzk2 I look forward to seeing your less complex solution and explanation.